# How to load a php page into a div and run its (java)scripts?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am a newbie in Javascript and I a trying to accomplish something certainly obvious, but I do not seem able to do it right.

I have a menu on the left, and there's one particular link which should load an external .php page in a certain destination div.

The .php page includes PHP statements like
  `echo "<script> blah blah blah </script>;"`

When I load the page these scripts are not executed.

I try to avoid using jQuery, but even with jQuery I do not seem able to make it work.

Could someone tell me how I should do it?

Calling page:

```
<script>

//jQuery method, jQuery loaded

function loadPage(destId, pagetoload){
                    $('<div id="info" />').load(pagetoload, function() {
                        $(this).appendTo(destId)
                                    .slideDown(3000);
                        });
                        return false;
                            }
</script>

<a id='assigncusts' href="javascript:loadPage('others', 'players.php')">Assign</a>
```

The called .php page:

```
<?PHP
function createDropdown($arr, $code_cust, $log) {

    echo "".$arr[$log]."";

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != $log){
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}

    }

    echo '</select>';
    } 

?>

//In a while loop:

    echo "<tr><td>".$row['player_name']."</td><td>";

    createDropdown($users_array, $row['player_name'], $row['Login']);

    echo "</td></tr>\n";
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: at the very least show the script tag that is being called in the menu page

Answer (score 1):

Create your `div` in html, then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#info").load("yourscript.php");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your passing the string 'others' to destId and doing `$(this).appendTo(destId)` -- it's basically do `[info div].appendTo('other')` searching for the TAG "other"

Instead try doing:

```
 $('#info').hide().load(pagetoload, function() {
     $(this).show().slideDown(3000);
 });
```

Or you might want `$('#' + divId)` it depends on where you want the page loaded to. The matched element before `.load()` is where the content will be automatically placed into.